# PDF document verify exception

Tags: java, pdf, itext

When I try to verify signed pdf document I get RuntimeException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: algorithm identifier 1.2.398.3.10.1.1.1.1 in key not recognised
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyFactory.createPublicKeyFromPublicKeyInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject.getPublicKey(Unknown Source)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7.<init>(PdfPKCS7.java:582)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7.<init>(PdfPKCS7.java:421)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.verifySignature(AcroFields.java:2307)
at Main.verifyPDF(Main.java:62)
at Main.main(Main.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

my verification piece of code looks like this:

```
    public static boolean verifyPDF(String fileToVerify, KeyStore trustedStore, CRL crl) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    List<CRL> crls = null;
    if (crl != null) {
        crls = new ArrayList<CRL>(1);
        crls.add(crl);
    }
    boolean result = false;
    PdfReader checker = new PdfReader(fileToVerify);
    AcroFields af = checker.getAcroFields();
    ArrayList<String> names = af.getSignatureNames();

    for (int k = 0; k < names.size(); ++k) {
        String name = (String) names.get(k);
        System.out.println("Signature: " + name);
        com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7 pk = af.verifySignature(name, "KALKAN");
        result = pk.verify();
        System.out.println("Signer certificate DN: " + pk.getSigningCertificate().getSubjectDN());
        Calendar cal = pk.getSignDate();
        X509Certificate pkc[] = (X509Certificate[]) pk.getSignCertificateChain();
        System.out.println("Document modified: " + !result);
        Object fails[] = PdfPKCS7.verifyCertificates(pkc, trustedStore, crls, cal);
        if (fails == null)
            System.out.println("Certificates verified against the KeyStore");
        else
            System.out.println("Certificate failed: " + fails[1]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

the exception occurs on this string:

```
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7 pk = af.verifySignature(name, "KALKAN");
```

I use patched iText library. I had to patch it because there was no algorithm like ECGOST34310 and I just added it. Signing is performed in usual way, there is no problem with it. 
Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to submit a pull request to add ECGOST34310!

Comment: In fact, if you use the AGPL iText, and anyone else uses your modification, then you are obligated to share your changes.

Comment: I would like to share, but don't know where can I expose it for public access. Recently will try to share in github

Answer (score 1):

At first glance that OID 1.2.398.3.10.1.1.1.1 seems to be defined by a Kazakh authority (cf. [this page](http://root.gov.kz/oid.html)), related to GOST 34,310-2.004 represented by the parent OID, without having yet been included in the mainstream BouncyCastle distribution, cf. the [BouncyCastle specifications](https://bouncycastle.org/specifications.html).

Thus, just like you have extended iText to be able to *sign* using GOST 34,310-2.004

> I use patched iText library. I had to patch it because there was no algorithm like ECGOST34310 and I just added it.

you have to extend it (or in this case more exactly the crypto library BouncyCastle used by iText) to be able to *verify* signatures using GOST 34,310-2.004. Maybe, though, someone else already has done that and comes forth to help?

By the way, it would be great if you shared the results as soon as they work.

---

That all been said I am not aware of GOST being mentioned in the context of either ISO 32000-1 or PAdES integrated PDF signatures. Using GOST for PDF signatures, therefore, will likely result in very limited interoperability.

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
accept
Looks like worked now.

In iText source replaced all BC jars with custom provider libs and re-compiled. The custom provider extends BC provider, thus, everithing matched and filled the "gaps", I mean missing algorithms. Now trying to validate signatures correctly and check if the document was modified. Have any idea how to do it?

Thank you guys!

Comment: *Have any idea how to do it?* - your code should do that already. If you have detailed questions, make them a stack overflow question in its own right.